How to correctly apply HoverTool to multiple hv.Points objects in a HoloViews plot?
I'm trying to plot a series of data points in a HoloViews plot with multiple scatter and line layers. Each set of data points has custom hover tooltips using HoverTool, and I want the hover tool to show specific information for predictions and measurements.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
def generate_plot(
    dummy_data: pd.DataFrame,
    selected_samples: pd.DataFrame,
    time_interval: int,
    model_details: pd.DataFrame,
    date_range: tuple[pd.Timestamp, pd.Timestamp],
    exclude_outliers: bool,
) -> hv.Overlay:
    # Define tooltips for hover functionality
    HOVER_TOOLTIP = """
    <div style="background-color:white; font-size: 12px;">
        <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td style="color: @color; text-align: end; font-weight: bold;">@data_type:</td>
            <td style="color: black; margin-left: 5px; font-weight: bold;">@value{%0.1f} MPa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: @color; text-align: end;">Date:</td>
            <td style="color: black; margin-left: 5px;">@date{%F}</td> <!-- Formatting Date -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: @color; text-align: end;">Sample ID:</td>
            <td style="color: black; margin-left: 5px;">@id</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: @color; text-align: end;">Sample Type:</td>
            <td style="color: black; margin-left: 5px;">@type</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    """
    
    hover_tool_1 = HoverTool(
        tooltips=HOVER_TOOLTIP,
        formatters={
            "@date": "datetime",
            "@value": "printf"
        }
    )
    
    hover_tool_2 = HoverTool(
        tooltips=HOVER_TOOLTIP,
        formatters={
            "@date": "datetime",
            "@value": "printf"
        }
    )

    def add_hover_tools_to_plot(plot, element):
        renderers = plot.handles['glyph_renderers']
        for renderer in renderers:
            if 'Prediction' in renderer.data_source.data['data_type']:
                hover_tool_1.renderers = [renderer]
                plot.state.add_tools(hover_tool_1)
            elif 'Measurement' in renderer.data_source.data['data_type']:
                hover_tool_2.renderers = [renderer]
                plot.state.add_tools(hover_tool_2)

    plot_overlay = hv.Overlay()

    # Generate prediction outlier points
    outlier_predictions = hv.Points(
        dummy_data,
        kdims=["date", "predicted_value"],
        vdims=["id", "type", "color", "value", "data_type"]
    ).opts(color='color', size=8)
    plot_overlay = plot_overlay * outlier_predictions

    # Generate measurement outlier points
    outlier_measurements = hv.Points(
        selected_samples,
        kdims=["date", f"strength_{time_interval}d"],
        vdims=["id", "type", "color", "value", "data_type"]
    ).opts(color='color', size=8)
    plot_overlay = plot_overlay * outlier_measurements

    # Add lines and scatter points for predictions
    prediction_line = hv.Curve(
        dummy_data,
        kdims=["date"],
        vdims=["predicted_value"]
    ).opts(line_width=2, color="blue", interpolation="steps-post")

    prediction_points = hv.Points(
        dummy_data,
        kdims=["date", "predicted_value"],
        vdims=["id", "type", "color", "value", "data_type"]
    ).opts(color='color', size=8)

    plot_overlay = plot_overlay * prediction_line * prediction_points

    # Add lines and scatter points for measurements
    measurement_line = hv.Curve(
        selected_samples,
        kdims=["date"],
        vdims=[f"strength_{time_interval}d"]
    ).opts(line_width=2, color="green", interpolation="steps-post")

    measurement_points = hv.Points(
        selected_samples,
        kdims=["date", f"strength_{time_interval}d"],
        vdims=["id", "type", "color", "value", "data_type"]
    ).opts(color='color', size=8, width=800)

    plot_overlay = plot_overlay * measurement_line * measurement_points

    # Apply hover tools to the overlay
    plot_overlay.opts(
        hooks=[add_hover_tools_to_plot],
        legend_position="top_left",
        width=800,
        tools=['pan', 'wheel_zoom', 'box_zoom', 'reset']
    )

    # Set date range for the x-axis
    plot_overlay = plot_overlay.redim.range(date=(date_range[0], date_range[1]))
    
    return plot_overlay


However, only one HoverTool works at a time, and I am unable to get both sets of hover tools to work simultaneously across different data layers. How can I apply HoverTool to both prediction and measurement points correctly?
Any suggestions or tips to resolve this issue would be much appreciated!
